# Used wrong two letter country code for xkblayout

Tags: keyboard

I did something very stupid. I typed the wrong two letter code when I tried to change my keyboard layout. Seems this code is not used, since I'm just typing squares afterwards... Any advices to get my settings back (default - whatever just let me type again).

Comment: Search for the appropriate config file, SSH into the Pi and make the necessary changes to the file. Failing that  backup any important data and re-flash the SD card.

Answer (score -1):

Ah found a solution. Get access via ssh! Thank you all nevertheless :)